# transfer of an HttpSession with some non-Serializable attributes between cluster nodes

Tags: java, servlets, serialization, httpsession, servlet-container

Let's assume that an `HttpSession`, that contains a mix of non-`Serializable` attributes and `Serializable` ones (that will actually serialize properly), needs to be transferred between cluster nodes. Does the Servlet spec requires container implementations to transfer all the `Serializable` attirbutes or are implementations free to decide that if some attributes are not `Serializable`, then nothing will be transferred or only those attributes that get serialized before the first serialization `Exception` occurs?

I hope, that such requirement exists in the specs, but I couldn't find any reliable confirmation.

Comment: The specification doesn't require any specific mechanism, but does require that all `Serializable` attributes are transferred, somehow or other. Servlet Specification #7.7.2 *Distributed Environments.* It's easy to find.

Comment: @user207421 many thanks!! :)